# Why doesn't intelliJ install the dependency

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I'm trying to add the following dependency in the pom.xml with IntelliJ

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The issue is that the spring-boot-devtools does not get added in my "External libraries" folder as it should as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#maven_dependency_multi_module

IntelliJ gives me the error :
Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:3.0.1' not found

Why is the new dependency not added properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the dependency installed, you have to right click on the pom.xml > Maven > Reload project.
The dependency gets added in the Externam Libraries folder and the error in pom.xml disappears